# How to use SQL Datareader and a foreach loop for Groupings of IDs? C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, foreach, while-loop

I have a table which has the results of student's marks for particular modules (classes).

[image: See table output in image]

I take the mark percentage and multiply it against a value from the assessment table (based on the assessment ID). This part all works fine.

I tried to write a loop using the SQL data reader, to add up all the values FOR EACH MODULE. However, I can only seem to add up all the values altogether for a particular user (it's in the where clause). I can't put the `moduleID = 1` in the `WHERE` clause because I need to see all results at once.

Here's the code I've already attempted, which adds up all the values for the user.

```
//set-up object to use the web.config file
string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["QSISConnection"].ConnectionString;

//set-up connection object called 'myConnection'
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

// open database communication
myConnection.Open();

// create the SQL statement
string query = "SELECT ModuleAssessmentUser.ModuleID, ModuleAssessmentUser.AssessmentID, MarkPercentage * Assessment.AssessmentWeighting AS FinalMark FROM ModuleAssessmentUser INNER JOIN[Assessment] ON(Assessment.AssessmentID = ModuleAssessmentUser.AssessmentID) WHERE (ModuleAssessmentUser.UserID = 2)";

// set-up SQL command and use the SQL and myConnection object
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);

// create a SqlDataReader object that asks for data from a table
SqlDataReader rdr = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

// create variable to add column values
int totalmark = 0;

// when in read mode ask for data
while (rdr.Read())
{
    // put variable value from moduleID column in local variable
    string usermodule = rdr["ModuleID"].ToString();

    // needs to be a text control called 'moduleid' on the aspx web page
    modulenumber.Text = usermodule.ToString();

    // get value of your weighting
    int fmark = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["FinalMark"]);

    // update the moduleweighting variable by adding the value in the column FinalMark
    // this is in a loop so should accumulate the values 
    totalmark = totalmark + fmark;
    result.Text = totalmark.ToString();
}

// once the adding up has been added up display total in final text box
// create a text control on aspx called 'result'
// need to convert int to string to display in text control
myConnection.Close();
```

I am still quite new to C# and ASP.NET, so any advice is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share some sample data and expected output ?

Comment: Can you use a SQLDataAdapter instead of the SqlDataReader?  The DataAdapter will put results into a DataTable and then you can use linq methods for summing columns of the DataTable.

Comment: Honestly, I didn't got what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya the sample data is in the image above, my expected output would be                                                                                                      Module 1 = (65 + 55), Module 2 = (72 + 80) etc

Answer (score 0):

Try code below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication12
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //set-up object to use the web.config file
            string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["QSISConnection"].ConnectionString;

            //set-up connection object called 'myConnection'
            SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

            // open database communication
            myConnection.Open();


            //create the SQL statement

            string query = "SELECT ModuleAssessmentUser.ModuleID, ModuleAssessmentUser.AssessmentID, MarkPercentage * Assessment.AssessmentWeighting AS FinalMark FROM ModuleAssessmentUser INNER JOIN[Assessment] ON(Assessment.AssessmentID = ModuleAssessmentUser.AssessmentID) WHERE (ModuleAssessmentUser.UserID = 2)";

            //set-up SQL command and use the SQL and myConnection object
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);


            //create a sqldatareader object that asks for dats from a table
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(myCommand);


            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

            int markPercentage = dt.AsEnumerable().Sum(x => x.Field<int>("MarkPercentage"));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Says dataGridView1 doesn't exist in current context and InitializeComponent(); can't be found either. my first line says               
 public partial class StudentAcademicRecord : System.Web.UI.Page, rather than how yours says form... I don't understand how to change it for mine?

Comment: I just created sample code since you didn't include all your code.  You have to add DGV to form manually and your webpage.

Comment: I added it and got that part fixed, but when I have the last line  of code I'm getting the error System.InvalidCastException
  HResult=0x80004002
  Message=Specified cast is not valid.
  Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
  StackTrace:
<Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>

Comment: Is the column defined in database as an integer?  Maybe you need : x => int.Parse(x.Field<string>("MarkPercentage"))   or some of the cells may be null so then : int? markPercentage = dt.AsEnumerable().Sum(x => x.Field<int?>("MarkPercentage"));